# How to run a mongoose query in a for loop and make res.render wait

Tags: node.js, mongoose

First of all, I apologize if the title is nonsensical. I'm just having a really hard time trying to explain what I'm having trouble with.

I'm trying to retrieve data from a collection with the help of data from another collection. Normally, running a query inside another query works just fine but introducing a for loop into the mix has made it impossibly difficult for me to fix.

So, here's what I'm trying to - I have a collection of objects inside an array called 'all_collections'. Each of these collections house another array called 'resources'. My objective is to retrieve the '_id' at index 0 of each object.

This is what I've attempted -

```
    router.get('/profile', mid.requiresLogin, function(req, res, next) {
        var output_collections = '';
        User.findOne({ _id: req.session.userId }, function(err, user) {
            for(var i=0; i<user.all_collections.length;i++) {
                Resource.findOne({_id:user.all_collections[i].resources[0]}, function(err, resource) {
                    output_collections += '<div>'+resource.image+'</div>';
                })
            }

        res.render('profile',{collections:output_collections});
     });
  });
```

I've also tried -

```
    var output_collections = [];
       User.findOne({ _id: req.session.userId }).then(function(user) {
          output_collections.push(user);
          for (var i = 0; i < user.all_collections.length; i++) {
               Resource.findOne({ _id: user.all_collections[i].resources[0] })
            .exec(function(error, resource) {
                output_collections.push('div>'+resource.image+'</div')
            });
    }
    console.log('1');
    return Promise.all(output_collections);
       }).then(function(output_collections) {
            console.log(output_collections);
            res.render('profile', {
               title: 'Profile',
               name: output_collections[0].name,
               email: output_collections[0].email,
               collections: output_collections
             })
     }).catch(function(error) {
          next(error);
     });
```

The 'output_collections' variable comes up empty outside of the for loop. I'm fairly certain it's the for loop that's creating the problem. If anyone could enlighten me on how to do this correctly (and if the usage of for here is completely wrong), I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Your code is correct. What is the problem occuring?

Comment: The variable output_collections comes up empty outside of the for loop. My understanding is that res.render is executed before the variable can be populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
router.get('/profile', mid.requiresLogin, async (req, res, next) => {
    let output_collections = []
    let user = await  User.findOne({ _id: req.session.userId })

    for(let i=0; i<user.all_collections.length;i++) {
         let rerource = await Resource.findOne({_id:user.all_collections[i].resources[0]})
         output_collections.push('<div>'+ resource.image+'</div>')

    }
    res.render('profile'，{collections:output_collections})
}）
```

Answer (score 0):

> The 'output_collections' variable comes up empty outside of the for loop.

This is because `Resource.findOne()` is an asynchronous call, by the time it finishes fetcing the data from db, `res.render()` would already be done.

> I'm fairly certain it's the for loop that's creating the problem. If anyone could enlighten me on how to do this correctly

Yes. You're right. `for` loops asynchronous tasks but expects result in synchronous fashion. You can change this by wrapping `Resource.findOne()` in a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Making those changes to your code,

```
'use strict';

let _ = require('lodash');

getUserDetailById(req.session.userId).then(user => {
  return Promise.all([
    user,
    getResourceDetailsForUser(user.all_collections)
  ]);
}).then(results => {
  let [{name, email}, collections] = results;
  res.render('profile', {
    title: 'Profile',
    name: name,
    email: email,
    collections: collections
  });
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Error occured when fetching resource', err);s
});

function getResourceDetailsForUser(collections) {
  if (_.isEmpty(collections)) {
    return [];
  }

  return _.map(collections, collection => {
    return Resource.findOne({
      _id: collection.resources[0]
    }).then((error, resource) => {
      return `<div>${resource.image}</div>`;
    });
  });
}

function getUserDetailById(userId) {
  return User.findOne({_id: userId});
}
```

Comment: Hi Sridhar. Thank you for taking the time to give me such a detailed answer. However, it isn't working as of yet and it's mainly due to my lack of understanding of the code you provided. 

In the getResourceDetailsForUser function, is it iterating through the collections object? Because it's supposed to go through each collection depending on the length of user.all_collections -

collection[0].resource[0]

collection[1}.resource[0]

Comment: @RajSaha  yes it does iterate over collections[i].resources[0].